# Build of dnx451 on VSTS is unable to resolve dependencies

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops

Trying to build a .xproj with dnx451 as framework works fine locally but not on Visual Studio online builds.

Log:

```
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231
Building DnxLibTests for DNX,Version=v4.5.1
Using Project dependency DnxLibTests 1.0.0
Source: C:\a\1\s\DnxLibTests\project.json
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.Abstractions 1.0.0-rc1-final
```

project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "DnxLibTests Class Library",
  "authors": [ "" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.1.0",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-rc1-build204"
  },
  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages of your project were not restored before build. To fix this issue, add following steps to run a dnu restore in your build process:

1. Create a PowerShell script with following code:

> Get-ChildItem -Path
>       $PSScriptRoot\src -Filter project.json -Recurse | ForEach-Object { &
>       dnu restore $_.FullName 2>1 }

2. Add the PowerShell script to your VSO repository.
3. Add a PowerShell step in the top of your build definition and select the script created in Step 1.
   [image]

Save the definition and queue a new build, the build should be completed successfully.

Comment: You got me in the right direction, I was actually already using the PreBuild.ps1 script but didn't check the path for the Restore command and since it was a restore in a class lib and not the src of a asp.net it worked.
This is the [link] to the PreBuild.ps1 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5